# Stop page refresh after form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, preventdefault

I have searched many other threads about this and I can't see what I am doing wrong, I am trying to send form values to a php file to send as an email, however the pages always refreshes. I have tried using event.preventDefault and return false both before and after my ajax call but none seem to work. What am I missing here here is my code.

HTML

```
<form method="post" name="registerForm" class="form">
    <label for="fullName" class="form__fullname form__label">Full Name</label>

    <input type="text" name="fullName" placeholder="Richard Thomson" maxlength="40" tabindex="1" pattern="^[a-zA-Z\s]*$" class="form__input" id="name" required>

    <label for="email" class="form__email form__label">Email</label>

    <input type="email" name="email"  placeholder="richard.thomson45@gmail.com" tabindex="2" class="form__input" id="email" required>

    <label for="telephone" class="form__tel form__label">Phone</label>

    <input type="tel" name="telephone" placeholder="07915834998" tabindex="3" pattern="[0-9]{11}" maxlength="11" class="form__input" id="telephone" required>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="form__submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

JS

```
var fullName,
    telephone,
    email,
    submitButton = $("#submit"),        
    formData;

submitButton.submit(function (event) {
    // event.preventDefault();

    fullName = $("#name").val();
    telephone = $("#telephone").val();
    email = $("#email").val();
    formData = {
        'name': fullName,
        'email': email,
        'telephone': telephone
    };

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'email.php',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            console.log("not working");
        });

    return false;
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['telephone'])) {

            if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $email = $_POST['email'];
            }

            if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/", $_POST['fullName'])) {
                $fullName = $_POST['fullName'];
            }

            if (preg_match("/[0-9]{11}/", $_POST['telephone'])) {
                $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
            }

            $telephone = substr_replace(substr_replace($telephone," ",3,0)," ",8,0);

            $emailTo = "test@hotmail.co.uk";
            $emailFrom = "contact@test.co.uk";
            $subject = "I would like to know more about test";
            $message = "Name:" . " " . $fullName . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= "Email:" . " " . $email . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= "Telephone:" . " " . $telephone;

            $headers = "From: $emailFrom \r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'; 
            $headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

            $success = mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $headers);

        } else {
            echo("Please fill all necessary fields");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: The submit event and preventDefault() function must be called on the form, not the submit button

Comment: `<form method="post" name="registerForm" class="form" action="javascript::">`

Comment: Use Button instead of submit.,

Comment: rather than using submit you can use button, submit button always refresh the page

Comment: @ishegg yes you were right

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript code to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preventing the default on the submit button should theoretically stop form submission—but:

1. there is no `submit` event for an input button. If you listen to `click`, that will work, but only partially because...
2. there might be other confounding factors that is interfering with this, i.e. other keystrokes or user interactions that causes the form to be submitted.

You should be listening to the `onsubmit` event fired from the form, instead of the event emitted from the submit button. The form's submit event is the definite event that is fired when a form is submitted: be it triggered by `<button>`, `<input type="submit">`, or even programatically, such as `$form.trigger('submit')`. You can give your form an ID, i.e.:

```
<form method="post" name="registerForm" class="form" id="registrationForm">
```

And then simply perform the exact same logic in the `onsubmit` callback:

```
$('#registrationForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    // Prevent form submission by the browser
    e.preventDefault();

    // Rest of the logic
});
```

If you can't modify the DOM such that you can identify the `<form>` element, using jQuery's DOM traversal methods will also work, i.e.:

```
var $form = submitButton.closest('form');
$form.on('submit', function(e) {
    // Prevent form submission by the browser
    e.preventDefault();

    // Rest of the logic
});
```

To illustrate my statement that the form's submit event serves as an "umbrella" that captures all submission events, regardless of how they are triggered, refer to the example I have attached below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    console.log('Form submission captured. It is triggered by: ', document.activeElement);
    //e.preventDefault();
  });
  
  $('#submitInput').on('submit', function(e) {
    console.log('Triggering submit event from <input>');
  });
  
  $('#submitButton').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Triggering submit event from <button type="submit" />');
  });

  $('#submitProgramatically').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Triggering submit event using JS only');
    $('#form').trigger('submit');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="#">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Just another text field" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit using an <input>" id="submitInput" />
  <br />
  <button id="submitButton">Submit using a &lt;button&gt;</button>
  <br />
  <a href="#" id="submitProgramatically">Submit programatically using JS</a>
</form>
```

Note: You can bypass jQuery's `onsubmit` event handler if you call the `submit()` method directly on the DOM node: `$('form')[0].submit()`.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the comment, I have updated my answer to clarify it. There might be other events that are triggering form submission, which does not trigger submit event on the button.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, although "ishegg" did point it out first, you are also correct, it was a silly mistake on my part